# Can an antenna damage an iPhone?

Tags: rf-electronics, electromagnetism

I am currently attending a radio technology course. We continuously work on radio sets that are sometimes used as manpacks by the Army. In order to learn how to operate them we work in close proximity to the sets and their antennas.

The antennas are generally whip type or long rods. Such as these :

[image]
[image]

The radio sets generally output around 25-50W in the 30-90MHz frequency range. Can that possibly cause damage to my iPhone?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a cross-post from [EE.SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/346138/11683).

Comment: Also posted on [ham.SE](https://ham.stackexchange.com/q/9657/4647)